# When using CreateprocessA/W does it use the system() function?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I was wondering, do the functions `CreateprocessA()` or `CreateprocessW()`  use or call `system()` or a variation of it when the command line argument is used and the first argument is left `NULL`?

**edit:**
otherwise, do they invoke CMD.EXE as an intermediary?

Comment: It's the other way around: system() calls CreateProcess(). You may actually be asking if there are any circumstances where CreateProcess invokes CMD.EXE as an intermediary; I don't know the answer to that one.

Comment: @zwol Thanks, I edited my question

Comment: I don't get the question. Are you asking, where the command line parser is? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) is one.

Comment: @zwol "*You may actually be asking if there are any circumstances where CreateProcess invokes CMD.EXE as an intermediary; I don't know the answer to that one*" - it doesn't.  Either it runs the specified file as-is as its own executable, or not at all.

Comment: How would cmd be invoked? That would be a separate process. Which would need to be created. By calling CreateProcess.

Comment: Hypothetically, `CreateProcess("thing.bat", ...)` could be rewritten internally as `CreateProcess("cmd.exe", "cmd /c thing.bat ...", ...)`.

Comment: @GiladRaz Do you have any problem when using these APIs?

Comment: @Ritahan-msft no, i was just wondering

Answer (score 6):

No.

It's probably the other way around, that `system` on Windows is implemented using `CreateProcess` (or `ShellExecute`, which in turn might be implemented using `CreateProcess`).

Comment: `system` calls `CreateProcessA` (multibyte) and `_wsystem` calls `CreateProcessW` (wide character), but both execute a command line that runs the `%ComSpec%` shell with the `/c` option to run a command, and this shell is almost always cmd.exe. Also, if `CreateProcess` is called to execute a .bat or .cmd file, it rewrites the command line to execute via the `%ComSpec%` shell with `/c`.

Comment: For an external command, CMD will in turn try to execute the command via `CreateProcessW`. If that fails, in most cases except a few error codes such as `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5) , CMD will retry via `ShellExecuteExW`. If CMD's `start` command is used, it will even retry with `ShellExecuteExW` if it can't find a file to execute in `PATH`, which allows running registered "App Paths" programs.